# How to write unit test case using jest in react?

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, reactjs, jestjs

I am writing unit test cases for one of my react app , there are some arrow functions and normal functions in class component,but i am not getting idea how to write for that? so how to trigger that next-Page function checking for its state value in test-case

```
 const setup = (   const store = storeFactory(initialState);

        return mountWithAppProvider(<Invoice  store = {store}/>);
    }

    const wrapper = setup();

      test('should pagination next page works properly', () => {
          wrapper.nextPage();   
      })


    renderInvoiceTotals() {
            let a = 0 ;
            let b = 0;
            let c = 0;

             c = a+b ;

             console.log("result :"c);


            }

    //arrow function

       nextPage = () => {
            const newPageNumber = this.state.currentPage + 1;
            this.setState({ currentPage: newPageNumber });
        };
```

> As per code , I want to call that nextPage function from my test file
>   but unable to call same for renderInvoice totals
>   So in my unit test case i just wanted to check that both functions in nextPage by triggering it i want check the state in expect

Comment: so you have a component and that component is basically a pagination where you have a nextPage link and when u click on the nextPage link or button it will call the function. Is that what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Yes I want to write test case for that nextPage

Comment: so on click of nextPage of pagination that nextPage method getting called

Answer (score 0):

The method you want to call resides inside the instance of the wrapper. That means you need to call it like this:

```
wrapper.instance().nextPage();
```

Setup your test file like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

describe('Testing component',() => {
  let wrapper = mount(<Invoice  store = {store} />)

  test('testing nextPage method', ()=>{
    wrapper.instance().nextPage();
    expect(wrapper.state('currentPage')).toEqual('the value you want here');
  });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: const setup = (initialState={}) => {
  
    const store = storeFactory(initialState);

    return mountWithAppProvider(<Invoice  store = {store}/>);
}     const wrapper = setup();  from this wrapper i am trying to get that method

Comment: Means my main motto is i called that method from test file trigger it just check the current page state of component , is it 1 or not in expect , so firstly i am unable to trigger that method , and unable to access component state so i can check it in expect

Comment: error is unable to access method of that class component , that next page is called when pagination next page click occurs

Comment: The way you are setting up your test file doesn't seem correct.

Comment: test('should pagination next page works properly', () => {

        let wrapper = mountWithAppProvider(<Invoice  store = {store} affiliate = {     wrapper.instance().nextPage();
          expect(wrapper.state('currentPage')).toEqual('the value you want here');
        
      // console.log("wrapper.instance().onNext()::",wrapper.renderInvoiceTotals());    
    
  }) as my class component using react-polaris component so i have to use 'mountWithAppProvider' instead of mount , but after that i getting following error  "wrapper.instance(...).nextPage is not a function"

Comment: i hope you have defined nextPage function in your Invoice component and have binded it as well. i.e. this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this)

Comment: I am not binded it ,used arrow function

Comment: try binding it inside constructor instead of arrow function